# Как эмулировать работу метода push?

Tags: javascript, массивы, push

На примере массива:

`massive6 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 700, 121];`

Вроде понимаю логику, но никак не могу дойти до истины:

```
btn6.onclick = f6;

function f6() {
    for (let i = 0; i < massive6.length; i++) {
        massive6[massive6.length - 1] = input6.value;
    }
    out6.textContent = massive6;
}
```

Comment: array[array.length] = newValue

Comment: Бесконечный цикл буду ловить.

Comment: А зачем там цикл?

Comment: Действительно, зачем я его туда впихнул? Спасибо!